# Quarter turn sprite sheets?

Tags: sprites, assets, isometric, spritesheet

I'm having trouble finding sprite sheets that have the characters turn in 8th movements, so that you can see back, front, left, right, and in between.  What would be a good *term* to search for when trying to find these kind of sprite sheets?

Comment: Is it for a top down or isometric game?

Comment: @ClassicThunder Sorry -- that would help.  Isometric.

Answer (score 2):

I just typed in "8 directional sprites" in google images and got some relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

You can google "isometric character sprite"